# asp.net copy table to clipboard

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, clipboard

How can I copy the contents of an asp:Table to the clipboard so that it can be pasted in something like Excel?

I assume some sort of JavaScript is required?

For winforms it is easy enough using the Clipboard object but how about for asp.net?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with browsers is that clipboard access is often a privileged access so you end up needing something like Flash.

There's a nice library out there I used a couple of times called ZeroClipboard - https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

Comment: So there is no quick JS way to do it? Well there is for simple text but how about for something complex like a table?

Comment: There isn't a quick way to do it, you'd have to come up with the code to pull the table and format it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A technique I saw somewhere said to open a popup, copy the data into it, pre-select it, and tell the user to press CTRL+C.  Sounds silly, but it is easy for the user and doesn't require any special privileges.

I started using it in a few sites and my users LOVE it. Everything is done in jQuery. Here's a screenshot from a transaction where users wanted to copy an HTML table into Excel. Clicking on a "Export to Excel" button produces this...

[image]